# My fourier series doesn't fit the graph

Tags: matlab, fft

I'm trying to plot a Fourier series that should fit the original graph (which is right), but I don't know what's wrong. I also double-checked the Fourier approximation.

The original graph is generated with:

```
t=-pi:0.01:0;
x=ones(size(t));
plot(t,x)
axis([-3*pi 3*pi -1 4])
hold on
t=0:0.01:pi;
y=cos(t);
plot(t,y)
```

whereas the Fourier series is generated with:

```
t=-pi:0.01:pi;
f=1/2;
for n=1:5
    costerm=0;
    if n/2== round(n/2)
        sinterm=((-2*n)/(pi*(1-n^2)))*sin(2*n*t); 
    else
        sinterm= (-2/(pi*n))*sin(2*n*t);
    end
    f=f+sinterm+costerm;
end
plot(t,f)
```

The graph looks like this:
[image]

Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: (1) What is the "original" graph? (2) `costerm` is always 0.  Is that intentional? (3) `f` is only one value yet in your `plot` syntax at the end, you are assuming it's a vector of values.  (4) Please post what the original signal is and/or the Fourier Series coefficients to represent the signal.  We can't tell whether it's working unless we can see what the coefficients are and/or the original graph you are speaking of.  It's hard to tell what the "original" graph is from your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that can be noticed is that the generated series in your plot runs for two periods in the support interval `[-pi:pi]`. This point to an incorrect constant in your `sin(2*n*t)` argument, which should instead be `sin(n*t)`.

Also, as a general rule

- odd functions have only `sin` terms
- even functions have only `cos` terms
- otherwise, the Fourier series contain a mixture of `sin` and `cos` terms.

In your case the function is neither even nor odd, so you should expect both `sin` and `cos` terms to be present. However you are only computing the `sinterm` and leaving `costerm=0`. More specifically, while the cosine series coefficients evaluate to 0 for all `n>1`, you are in fact missing the term for `n=1` which is `0.5*cos(t)`.

With these corrections you should get

```
f=1/2 + 0.5*cos(t);
for n=1:5
    if 0==mod(n,2)
        sinterm=((-2*n)/(pi*(1-n^2)))*sin(n*t); 
    else
        sinterm= (-2/(pi*n))*sin(n*t);
    end
    f=f+sinterm;
end
```

which should give you the following plot (blue line being the original function, and the red line being the Fourier series expansion):

[image]